# Predecessor within group satisfying a property

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a `pandas DataFrame` where rows corresponds to chronological events with a time column `t` and an indicator whether an certain even happened or not. I want to add an additional column about the last time that event did happen, and an additional column for last time the event did not happen, within that group. Cases before witnessing this are set to `NaN`. Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'group_id':[1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3], 't':[1, 5, 9, 12, 100, 120, 150, 180, 400, 410, 450, 490], 
                             'happened': [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,  1, 1, 0]})

out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'group_id':[1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3], 't':[1, 5, 9, 12, 100, 120, 150, 180, 400, 410, 450, 490],
                              'happened': [1, 0, 1, 0,     0, 0, 1, 0,    1,  1, 1, 0],
                             't_yes': [np.nan, 1, 1, 9,     np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 150,    np.nan, 400, 410, 450],
                             't_no': [np.nan, np.nan, 5, 5,     np.nan, 100, 120, 120,    np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
                             })
```

I know it has something to do with `groupby` and probably `shift`, but I don't know exactly how

Answer (score 0):

First multiply `t`s with `happened`s to see if an event happened or not at any point in time. Since we want `t_yes`, `t_no` separately, we multiply separately. Then use `groupby.apply` to get the last time event `happened` through `shift` + `ffill`.

```py
df['t_yes'] = df['happened'].mul(df['t']).replace(0, float('nan'))
df['t_no'] = (~df['happened'].astype(bool)).mul(df['t']).replace(0, float('nan'))
df[['t_yes','t_no']] = df.groupby('group_id')[['t_yes','t_no']].apply(lambda x: x.shift().ffill())
```

Output:

```py
    group_id    t  happened  t_yes   t_no
0          1    1         1    NaN    NaN
1          1    5         0    1.0    NaN
2          1    9         1    1.0    5.0
3          1   12         0    9.0    5.0
4          2  100         0    NaN    NaN
5          2  120         0    NaN  100.0
6          2  150         1    NaN  120.0
7          2  180         0  150.0  120.0
8          3  400         1    NaN    NaN
9          3  410         1  400.0    NaN
10         3  450         1  410.0    NaN
11         3  490         0  450.0    NaN
```

---

Another a bit more involved solution:

First `pivot` the DataFrame. Then multiply the values with `t` with `happened`s to see if an event happened or not at any point in time. Then `stack` + `reindex` will get the pivoted DataFrame back into the original shape. Finally, `groupby.apply` will get us the desired output: the last time event `happened`:

```py
pivoted = df.pivot('group_id', 't', 'happened')
df['t_yes'] = pivoted.replace(0, float('nan')).mul(pivoted.columns).stack().reindex([df['group_id'], df['t']]).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().shift()).reset_index(drop=True)
df['t_no'] = pivoted.replace({1:float('nan'), 0:1}).mul(pivoted.columns).stack().reindex([df['group_id'], df['t']]).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().shift()).reset_index(drop=True)
```